# Why is dh_autoreconf_clean patching ltmain.sh?

Tags: build, debian, vlc, packaging, lintian

.. and why does it break my packaging build?

I am trying to build .deb packages for the latest git version of VLC.

Namely, I'm taking the "/debian" directory from my distros (ubuntu 15.10) source package for VLC (2.2.1) and copying/applying this to the latest git pull of VLC (which I am able to compile without problems).

When I run "debuild -b -uc -us" (works for VLC 2.2.1) for the git version, I get:

```
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture amd64
fakeroot debian/rules clean
dh clean --parallel --with autoreconf
dh_autoreconf_clean
patching file ./autotools/ltmain.sh
Hunk #1 FAILED at 5800.
Hunk #2 FAILED at 6168.
2 out of 2 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file ./autotools /ltmain.sh.rej
dh_autoreconf_clean: patch -R -f --no-backup-if-mismatch -i /usr/share/dh-autoreconf/ltmain-as-needed.diff ./autotools/ltmain.sh  
returned exit code 1
debian/rules:246: recipe for target 'clean' failed
make: *** [clean] Error 25
dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules clean gave error exit status 2
debuild: fatal error at line 1374:
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -D -us -uc -b failed
```

Building debian packages is nasty and the information is a bit scarce.
Any idea where such an error message might come from and why?

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem, and was unable to find anything on Google except this question.

I deleted two files present in the Debian file I used, `autoreconf.after` and `autoreconf.before`.